# Unique Constraints on a DataTable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable, constraints

I have a datatable with 2 columns: 
(1) Customer Name 
(2) Customer ID

The source of this datatable is a database with many combinations of Customer Name and Customer ID. What I need in my datatable is a unique combination of Customer Name and Customer ID. If the datatable already contains the same combination, I would want it to "pass over" the items. In my code, an error keeps appearing when it encounters same combination (thus, preventing me to complete my datatable). Is there any way to prevent this?

```
    Dim parameters As New DataTable

    parameters.Columns.Add("Customer Name", GetType(String))
    parameters.Columns.Add("Customer ID", GetType(String))
    Dim myUniqueConstraint = New UniqueConstraint(New DataColumn() {parameters.Columns(0), parameters.Columns(1)})
    parameters.Constraints.Add(myUniqueConstraint)
    Dim row_param As DataRow
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to filter your data source so that you only have unique items.

If the source is a database you could use "SELECT DISTINCT" when querying the database.  Or alternatively use Linq's `Distinct` method to filter in code.

The alternative is to check for the presence of each item before adding a row, i.e. you would need to "pass over" duplicates yourself.

Comment: Can I use "SELECT DISTINCT" on combination of entries?

Comment: @lulutanseco - sure: "SELECT DISTINCT CustomerName, CustomerID FROM ...".